# Why can a reduce helper destructure a vector when reducing over a map?

Tags: clojure

I am confused by the following piece of code in Clojure. The code works. However, I don't understand that within the anonymous function, when we pass in the parameters `[new-map [key val]]`, we are explicitly telling Clojure to expect an argument in a **vector form** of `[key val]` and *destructure it* but we are passing in a **hash** `{:max 30 :min 10}`. It doesn't make sense to me at all.

Shouldn't the parameters be `[new-map {:key val}]` if we are going to pass a hash into the function? Can someone explain to me where did my logic go wrong ?

```
(reduce (fn [new-map [key val]]
          (assoc new-map key (inc val)))
        {}
        {:max 30 :min 10})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
user=> (type [:plum 8])
clojure.lang.PersistentVector
user=> (def mymap {:apple 1 :banana 2 :orange 10 :plum 8})
#'user/mymap
user=> (type mymap)
clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap
user=> (first mymap)
[:plum 8]
user=> (type (first mymap))
clojure.lang.MapEntry
```

[In the docs](http://clojure.org/data_structures), about half-way down the page:

> A map entry is treated as an ordered collection of key and value.

[MapEntry](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/MapEntry.java) extends [AMapEntry](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/AMapEntry.java), which extends [APersistentVector](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/APersistentVector.java), which is also extended by [PersistentVector](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentVector.java) (the one you are familiar with).

Short version is, you can iterate over maps' entries, and every entry in a map is like a vector, with exactly that structure: `[key value]`.

Answer (score 2):

`{:key1 :val1, :key2 :val2}` turns into `'([:key1 :val1] [:key2 :val2])` (albeit not necessarily in that order) when traversed as a sequence. Here, `reduce` is traversing it in just that way, and passing each pair into the reducer function individually.